# TypeLoadException in ASP.NET DevExtreme Datagrid when specifying columns

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress, devextreme

I'm customizing the columns I need for a datagrid in DevExtreme. Below is my Index.cshtml and my action method to load the data. The model has more attributes but I only want to include these three.

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<ServicingRequestOrder.Models.GeneralInfo>
()
.ID("dataGrid")
.ShowBorders(true)
.DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("GeneralInfo").LoadAction("IndexLoad").Key("ID"))
.Columns(columns =>
{
    columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerID);
    columns.AddFor(m => m.Name);
    columns.AddFor(m => m.Description);
}).

[HttpGet]
public object IndexLoad(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
{
    var generalInfos = _context.GeneralInfos.ToList();
    return DataSourceLoader.Load(generalInfos, loadOptions);
}
```

The specific exception I'm getting is

```
TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ExpressionHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=3.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.
```

I have included this service in my Startup.cs as well.

```
 services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

What am I missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is resolved. By default when I installed Devextreme in the dependencies, it wasn't the latest version. After some checking, I had to update the version of Devextreme and it's all good now.

Answer (score 1):

> TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal.ExpressionHelper' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures, Version=3.1.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

In ASP.NET Core 3.0, some pubinternal APIs (includes `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal` namespace) are updated to be truly internal, which seems cause this issue.

For more information about "Making "pubinternal" types in MVC internal", please check this link: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4932 .

As a possible workaround, you can try to setup the project with ASP.NET Core 2.x rather than ASP.NET Core 3+ version.

Comment: Thanks for the post, but I just had to update to the latest version of DevExtreme.

Comment: Ok, the issue seems that you are using older version of Devextreme that would use `ExpressionHelper` from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal`. Glad to hear the problem has been resolved :).

Comment: Hi @PlarentHaxhidauti, you can mark your solution as answer, which would help other community quickly find this case and fix similar issue.

Comment: I will as soon as I can, which is in two days. Thanks again :-))